# PDO fetch always returns false in PHP

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm trying to run a simple query with PDO in PHP. The code is pretty simple:

```
try {

    $sql_query = "select * from Articles where title=':article'";
    $dbh = get_PDO_connection();
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql_query);
    $stmt->execute( array( ':article' => "MD Example") );
    var_dump($stmt);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    //if($row==null)return 'null';
    var_dump($row);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage ();
}
```

`var_dump($stmt)` always prints:

```
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(45) "select * from Articles where title=':article'" }
```

... no matter what I put into `execute()`, with no exceptions thrown. And, as the title states, `fetch()` always returns false. You should know that if I "hard-code" the SQL query into the string, all of this works fine. In other words, if I set `$sql_query` to "select * from Articles where title='MD Example'", then `fetch()` returns the expected results. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes from around the placeholder:

```
$sql_query = "select * from Articles where title=:article";
//---------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
```

By using a placeholder, you relinquish responsibility for having to correctly quote strings or not quote numeric values. That becomes the business of PDO to correctly escape and quote the inputs for you.

By leaving in the quotes, rather than use the placeholder, PDO will literally be querying for the value `:article`  in the `title` column, rather than the value you pass to the `execute()` array.

Comment: Probably the fastest answer I've gotten here. I'll accept it once the 10 minute wait is over.